# Liferay 7.3: How can I use custom ADTs in a page template?

Tags: liferay, freemarker, liferay-7, liferay-7.3

I want to have ready components for a page, when a page template is used. E.g. when I create a page using `subpage-1` template, it'd give a place to drop a banner image (or leave a template image) and add breadcrumbs automatically (no need to customise).

They both have custom ADT, which I can't seem to find from the Page Template options. (It seems to have it's own "site" in the admin bar, when editing the template, so my guess is it doesn't find anything from my main site.)

**Is there a way to get the custom ADTs for the page template?** For clearance, the route to the template is `Site Builder --> Page Templates --> New Collection --> New page template`.

---

**Possible workaround?**

This is my `subpage-1-column.ftl` code, which has two dropping places: One for the banner image and breadcrumbs (which I would like to have automatically placed) and the other for the other stuff. Is it possible to add all the things here, that I want my page template to do (content place, type, adt...)?

```html
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid subpage-1-column">
    <div class="portlet-layout row no-gutters">
        <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only col-12" id="column-1">
            ${processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")}
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="portlet-layout row no-gutters">
        <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only col-12" id="column-2">
            ${processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")}
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried with ADT in the global scope? Also, consider ContentPages/Master Pages as yet another way to solve the problem with less effort than ADTs

Comment: I have no idea, why I haven't tried that! Global scope seems to solve the problem, thank you!!! Is there any downside to using the global scope ADTs? PS. Master Pages seemed to destroy my footer, header etc. so I didn't play around with them too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Promoting a comment to answer:

ADTs can live in global scope, there they're independent of a "current site".

Downside: Global means global and comes with the general downside of anything global. In this case, I believe that it's not much of a problem, but you'll have to validate that for yourself.

My recommendation is to look at Content Pages / Master Pages though, as they're *a lot* easier to edit than Freemarker Templates.

In your comment you say that Master Pages "destroy" your footer, header etc, which they're not supposed to do and I wonder about the root cause there. But anyway: You seem to have your ADT already, and global scope seems to fix your issue. I'll leave it at that. Going after the Master Page issue's root cause would be a different question (but might no longer be programming related)

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a code template for the possible "workaround":

```
<div id="main-content" class="container-fluid subpage-1-column">
  <div class="portlet-layout row no-gutters">
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only col-12" id="column-1">
        ${processor.processColumn("column-1", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")}

        <#assign portletPreferences = { "displayStyle" : "ddmTemplate_ADT_CUSTOM", "portletSetupPortletDecoratorId": "borderless", "headerType" : "none", "delta" : "10", "paginationType" : "none" } />

        ${processor.processPortlet("com_liferay_asset_publisher_web_portlet_AssetPublisherPortlet", portletPreferences)}
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="portlet-layout row no-gutters">
    <div class="portlet-column portlet-column-only col-12" id="column-2">
        ${processor.processColumn("column-2", "portlet-column-content portlet-column-content-only")}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This will add an AssetPublisher to your first column with a specific ADT (ddmTemplateKey = ADT_CUSTOM)

To see all available portletPreferences check your database or copy the following code in one of your ADTs:

```
<#list portletPreferences?keys as prop >
<li>
    ${prop}
</li>
</#list>
```